# module [] is not installed -- registering custom C++ wrapper for QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, app-manager

I need to access a C++ API to work with CAN bus. Looks like the best solution is to write a QML wrapper to expose all the functionality I need.

Here is my `canservice.cpp` so far:

```
#include "canservice.h"
#include <QCanBus>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCanBusFrame>
#include <QTimer>

#include <QtCore/qbytearray.h>
#include <QtCore/qvariant.h>
#include <QtCore/qdebug.h>

CANService::CANService(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_canDevice(nullptr)
{
    QString status = "";

    initializeSettings();


    // TODO" disable sending messages until connection is stablished
}

CANService::~CANService()
{
    delete m_canDevice;
}

void CANService::receiveError(QCanBusDevice::CanBusError error) const
{
    switch (error) {
        case QCanBusDevice::ReadError:
        case QCanBusDevice::WriteError:
        case QCanBusDevice::ConnectionError:
        case QCanBusDevice::ConfigurationError:
        case QCanBusDevice::UnknownError:
            qWarning() << m_canDevice->errorString();
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void CANService::initializeSettings()
{
    foreach (const QByteArray &backend, QCanBus::instance()->plugins()) {
        qInfo() << "found: " + backend;
        if (backend == "socketcan") {
            // found socketcan
            m_currentSettings.backendName = "socketcan";
            break;
        }
    }

    if(m_currentSettings.backendName.length() < 1) {
        qWarning() << "did not find a backend";
    }

    m_currentSettings.backendName = "socketcan";
    m_currentSettings.deviceInterfaceName = QStringLiteral("vcan0");
}

void CANService::connectDevice()
{
    m_canDevice = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice(m_currentSettings.backendName.toLocal8Bit(), m_currentSettings.deviceInterfaceName);
    if (!m_canDevice) {
        showStatusMessage(tr("Connection error"));
        return;
    }
    connect(m_canDevice, &QCanBusDevice::errorOccurred,
            this, &MainWindow::receiveError);
    connect(m_canDevice, &QCanBusDevice::framesReceived,
            this, &MainWindow::checkMessages);
    connect(m_canDevice, &QCanBusDevice::framesWritten,
            this, &MainWindow::framesWritten);

    if (p.useConfigurationEnabled) {
        foreach (const ConnectDialog::ConfigurationItem &item, p.configurations)
            m_canDevice->setConfigurationParameter(item.first, item.second);
    }

    if (!m_canDevice->connectDevice()) {
        delete m_canDevice;
        m_canDevice = nullptr;
        qInfo() << "Connection error";
    } else {
        qInfo() << m_currentSettings.backendName << "is connected";
    }
}

void CANService::sendMessage() const
{
    if (!m_canDevice)
        return;

    // TODO: replace test message with input
    QByteArray writings = dataFromHex("1122334455667788");

    QCanBusFrame frame;
    const int maxPayload = 8; // 64 : 8;
    int size = writings.size();
    if (size > maxPayload)
        size = maxPayload;
    writings = writings.left(size);
    frame.setPayload(writings);

    //TODO: get from UI
    qint32 id = 100;
    if (id > 2047) {
        //11 bits
        id = 2047;
    }

    frame.setFrameId(id);
    frame.setExtendedFrameFormat(true);

    // frame.setFrameType(QCanBusFrame::RemoteRequestFrame);
    // frame.setFrameType(QCanBusFrame::ErrorFrame);
    frame.setFrameType(QCanBusFrame::DataFrame);

    m_canDevice->writeFrame(frame);
}

void CANService::checkMessages()
{
    if (!m_canDevice)
        return;

    const QCanBusFrame frame = m_canDevice->readFrame();

    const qint8 dataLength = frame.payload().size();

    const qint32 id = frame.frameId();

    QString view;
    if (frame.frameType() == QCanBusFrame::ErrorFrame) {
        interpretError(view, frame);
    } else {
        view += QLatin1String("Id: ");
        view += QString::number(id, 16).toUpper();
        view += QLatin1String(" bytes: ");
        view += QString::number(dataLength, 10);
        view += QLatin1String(" data: ");
        view += dataToHex(frame.payload());
    }

    if (frame.frameType() == QCanBusFrame::RemoteRequestFrame) {
        qInfo() << "got remote request message" << view;
    } else if (frame.frameType() == QCanBusFrame::ErrorFrame) {
        qWarning() << "got can error frame: " << view;
    } else {
        qInfo() << "got can frame: " << view;
    }
}

void CANService::interpretError(QString &view, const QCanBusFrame &frame)
{
    if (!m_canDevice)
        return;

    view = m_canDevice->interpretErrorFrame(frame);
}

static QByteArray dataToHex(const QByteArray &data)
{
    QByteArray result = data.toHex().toUpper();

    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i += 3)
        result.insert(i, ' ');

    return result;
}

static QByteArray dataFromHex(const QString &hex)
{
    QByteArray line = hex.toLatin1();
    line.replace(' ', QByteArray());
    return QByteArray::fromHex(line);
}
```

In the `canservice.h` I have:

```
#ifndef CANSERVICE_H
#define CANSERVICE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QCanBusDevice>


class CANService : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CANService(QObject *parent = 0);
    typedef QPair<QCanBusDevice::ConfigurationKey, QVariant> ConfigurationItem;

    struct Settings {
        QString backendName;
        QString deviceInterfaceName;
        QList<ConfigurationItem> configurations;
        bool useConfigurationEnabled;
    };


    void connectDevice();

    Q_INVOKABLE void connect(const QString &query) {
        qDebug() << "invoking connect with " << query;


    }

    explicit ConnectDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ConnectDialog();

    Settings settings() const;

private:
    Settings m_currentSettings;
    void initializeSettings();


signals:

public slots:

};

qmlRegisterType<MyObject>("can.myapp", 1, 0, "CANService");

#endif // CANSERVICE_H
```

In my QML file I first attempt to import the newly defined service: `import can.myapp 1.0` and then I declare an instance of it:

```
CANService {
    id: "myCanService"
}
```

When I try to run this application and load the QML file that makes the call to `CANService`, it does not load and I get the following error in application console:

```
 component not ready:
 "file:///home/aras/Projects/myapp/apps/com.myapp.diagnostics/Diagnostics.qml:5 module \"can.myapp\" is not installed\n"
```

**EDIT**:
Problem is most likely with where I am calling `qmlRegisterType`. I am using `appman` so my application has no `main` function. Where is the right place to run `qmlRegisterType` from?

Comment: This might interest you http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/groups/qt-can-2.0

Answer (score 2):

I'm responding because you tagged an older post as similar.

Here's a couple questions:
1) Where are you calling `qmlRegisterType<MyObject>("can.myapp", 1, 0, "CANService");` My understanding is that this needs to be called in the `main` method before you instantiate the `QtQuickApplicationViewer` (if you're loading it that way.)

2) Does this work with a simple example (passing a simple `QString` value to a function)?

I'm not actively coding in Qt right at the moment, but hopefully this can point you in the right direction:

Here's the "main" method from one of my applications that uses custom components (for simple Java connectivity over the command line).

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtQml>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include "globals.h"
#include "lightassistant.h"
#include "reporting.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    //C++ Types
    qmlRegisterType<LightAssistant>("com.lightassistant", 1, 0, "LightAssistant");
    qmlRegisterType<Reporting>("com.lightassistant", 1, 0, "Reporting");
    //Singletons
    //qmlRegisterSingletonType(QUrl("file:///qml/LightAssistant/Styles.qml"), "com.lightassistant", 1, 0, "Styles");

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/LightAssistant/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();
    qDebug() << "offline path is " << viewer.engine()->offlineStoragePath();
    LA::OFFLINE_STORAGE_PATH = viewer.engine()->offlineStoragePath();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Here's a simplified class (these classes are ~600 lines)

```
#ifndefLIGHTASSISTANT_H
#define LIGHTASSISTANT_H

#include <QtSql>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtXml>
#include <QtXmlPatterns>
#include "globals.h"



class LightAssistant : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit LightAssistant(QObject *parent = 0);

        /**
         * Is this running on Android?
         */
        Q_INVOKABLE
        int isAndroid()
        {
           #ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
           return 1;
           #else
           return 0;
           #endif
        }

        /**
         * Is this running on Android?
         */
        Q_INVOKABLE
        int isIOS()
        {
           #ifdef Q_OS_IOS
           return 1;
           #else
           return 0;
           #endif
        }

        /**
         * @brief isMobile is this on a mobile device?
         * @return
         */
        Q_INVOKABLE
        int isMobile()
        {
            return isIOS() + isAndroid();
        }
        ....
        }
#endif // LIGHTASSISTANT_H
```

Theoretically you can invoke this in QML as such now:

```
import com.lightassistant 1.0
Item {
  LightAssistant {
    id: la
  }

  function isIos(){
    return la.isIOS();
  }

}
```

I would suggest doing something really simple like this to make sure there isn't a problem in the plumbing and then, if that works, go method by method to see if there's another call that's blocking something. My best guess without full source is that it is probably where you're registering the components.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I think you are right, I put `qmlRegisterType<MyObject>...`  in the header file which seems incorrect. But since I am using `appman` my application does not have a `main` method. Any idea where I could do the registering?

Comment: @Aras I'm at a loss for appman as I've never used it. I would try any `initialize` methods to see if you can load before the QML viewer starts, but barring that I would reach out to the developers directly and see if they can give you a hook to tie it in. Good luck!

Comment: I usually do the registrations in their `*.cpp` files: `const int registration = qmlRegisterType<...>`. These variables are created before `main()` is executed. A bit dangerous, but haven't had any problems yet.