# How can a C++ QObject be created inside a QML javascript function block?

Tags: qt, qml, qobject

[Similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923617/how-to-create-and-use-c-objects-in-qml-javascript), I want to instantiate a sub-class of QObject, ***but*** I want to do this in a javascript function block itself.

I have a class:

```
class CoverageKind : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT    
public:

  int64_t        id;
  QString        coverage_kind;

  CoverageKind(QObject * parent=nullptr);

  Q_PROPERTY(int64_t id MEMBER id NOTIFY id_changed)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString coverage_kind MEMBER coverage_kind NOTIFY coverage_kind_changed)

signals:
  void id_changed();
  void coverage_kind_changed();
};
```

This is registered with QML like:

```
qmlRegisterType<CoverageKind>("com.example.CoverageKind", 0, 1, "CoverageKind");
```

After importing `com.example.CoverageKind`, I can instantiate this QObject subclass like:

```
Item {
  CoverageKind {
    id: ck
    Component.onCompleted: {
      console.log('Created CoverageKind! ', ck);
    }
  }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Created CoverageKind!  CoverageKind(0x19b51b0)
```

However, if I do:

```
import com.example.CoverageKind 0.1;
Item {
  CoverageKind ck;
  Component.onCompleted: {
    ck = new CoverageKind();
  }
}
```

I get `TypeError: Type error` on the `ck = new ...` line.

I there an idiomatic way that can I instantiate a C++ QObject subclass from a QML javascript block?

I can do

```
var ck = Qt.createComponent("import com.example.CoverageKind 0.1; CoverageKind{}");
```

This feels really clunky.  I could also create a factory function, but I was hoping to be able to create these objects inside of javascript more ergonomically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` does not exist in `QML`, and the closest thing to what you want is to create property of type `CoverageKind` that is null initially and in [`Component.onCompleted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal) you will be assigned the value created with [`Qt.createQmlObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method).

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import com.example.CoverageKind 0.1;

Item {
    id: parentItem
    property CoverageKind ck: null
    Component.onCompleted: {
        ck = Qt.createQmlObject('import com.example.CoverageKind 0.1; CoverageKind{}',
                                parentItem,
                                "dynamicSnippet1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your item into a component

```
Component {
  id: myComponent
  CoverageKind {}
}
```

Then anywhere you can do:

```
var ckobj = myComponent.createObject (/*...*/)
```

Now `ckobj` is a new instance